# Foreach item i in collection of lists

Tags: c#, linq, list

Is there a classy way to do:

```
foreach(item i in ListItems1)
do ...
foreach(item i in ListItems2)
do ...
foreach(item i in ListItems2)
do ...
...
```

In a single foreach (using Linq I suppose ?)  in C#, that does not hurt performance (especially the memory side) ?

Comment: What are the ListItem objects?  Are they of the same type?

Comment: @GregtheIncredulous yes they are

Comment: I don't see why it would benefit you, but you could append them all to the same list to start with, using ListItems1.AddRange(ListItems2) etc and then process them all together, but you specify that you want to reduce memory usage rather than increase it so your current method is probably the best.  If you're worried about repeated code then factor it out into a function that you call 3 times...

Comment: i believe `foreach(item i in ListItems1.Union(ListItems2).Union(ListItems3))` will not lead to any significant memory overhead.

Comment: @MadSorcerer hmm i suppose that must be the only way, thanks for the comment

Comment: I agree with @GregtheIncredulous Just factor the code into a method and call it per list: `this.DoStuff(ListItems1); // repeat x2'

Comment: @GregtheIncredulous now i actually realized what you said, it looks like a good method as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to manage this is to factor it into a function that you call 3 times:

```
public void ProcessList(List<myListType> theList)
{
    //Do some cool stuff here...
}
```

But it's borderline whether you get much maintainability benefit with this.  If you don't want to increase memory usage then this is probably the best refactor to make your code better.  Unless your lists are huge the memory differences are likely to be negligible anyway.

Comment: This is also the cleanest way to go.  If the loop code is some 100~ lines of code, refactoring into a method makes for cleaner, more maintainable, single-purpose code.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do

```
foreach (item i in ListItems1.Concat(ListItems2).Concat(ListItems3))
{
    // do things
}
```

There's also the similar `.Union()` that removes duplicate items. However, since it is removing duplicates, it's less performant.

Comment: +1 for distinguishing between `Union` and `Concat`. -1 for pointing it out before me (but I'm not that mean)

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of answering your question and being a little creative, this here "technically" would work but I wouldn't advice using it.

```
int listItemTotalItemCount = ListItems1.Count() + ListItems2.Count() + ListItems3.Count();
for(int i = 0; i < listItemTotalItemCount; i++)
{
    int listIndex = i;
    object retrievedItem;
    if(listIndex >= ListItems1.Count())
    {
        if (i - ListItems1.Count() >= ListItems2.Count())
        {
            retrievedItem = ListItems3[i - ListItems1.Count()- ListItems2.Count() ];
        }
        else
        {
            retrievedItem = ListItems2[i - ListItems1.Count()];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        retrievedItem = ListItems1[listIndex];
    }

    retrievedItem.DoSomethingSpecial();
}
```

This can probably be improved as well with an array of the lists you want to iterate over, but as I said before I would not recommend this method as it is I'm guessing significantly worse than your original method.